# Get notified when PKToolPicker is visible in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, qlpreviewcontroller, pencilkit

I currently show a `QLPreviewController` in a SwiftUI app using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` - here is the code:

```
struct QLPDFPreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController,
                                context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: QLPDFPreviewController
        
        init(parent: QLPDFPreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let url = parent.url else { return NSURL(string: "")! }
            return url as NSURL
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                               editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
            .updateContents
        }
    }
}
```

I use this to display a PDF and using the `QLPreviewController` the user can input text into the PDF and draw on the PDF.

Everything works fine in terms of functionality. I now have a requirement to do some processing when either the keyboard has opened or the `PKToolPicker` is open within the `QLPreviewController`.

Listening for keyboard events is fine as I could use the `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` notification, however, I could not find something similar to get notified when the `PKToolPicker` is open.

I did come across `func toolPickerVisibilityDidChange(PKToolPicker)` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pktoolpickerobserver), however, it seems like we can only use this if we initialize our own `PKToolPicker`.

Is there any generic way to listen to whether a `PKToolPicker` is visible similar to something we do for the keyboard ?